# Using sed, prepend line only once, if there's a match later in file content

Tags: sed

I'd like to add a line on top of my output if my input file has a specific word.
However, if I'm just looking for specific string, then as I understand it, it's too late. The first line is already in the output and I can't prepend to it anymore.

Here's an exemple of input.

```
one
two
two
three
```

If I can find a line with, say, the word `two`, I'd like to add a new line before the first one, with for example `FOUND`. I want that line prepended only once, even if there are several matches.

So an input file without any `two` would remain unchanged, and the example file above would become:

```
FOUND
one
two
two
three
```

I know how to prepend with `i\`, but can't get the context right. From what I understood that would be around:

```
1{
/two/{   # This will will search "two" in the first line, how to look for it in the whole file ?
1i\
FOUND
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I know how to do it using other languages/methods, that's not my question.

Sed has advanced features to work on several lines at once, append/prepend lines and is not limited to substitution. I have a sed file already filled with expressions to modify a python source file, which is why I'd prefer to avoid using something else. I want to be able to add an import at the beginning of a file if a certain class is used.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -i.bak -0077 -pE 'say "FOUND" if /two/;' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.
`-E` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file. Also enables all optional features. Here, enables `say`.
`-0777` : Slurp files whole.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 0):

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual strings, that's not what you're trying to do so you shouldn't bother trying to use sed. There's lots of ways to do this, this one will be very efficient, robust and portable to all Unix systems:

```
$ grep -Fq 'two' file && echo "FOUND"; cat file
FOUND
one
two
two
three
```

To operate on a stream instead of (or in addition to) a file and without needing to read the whole input into memory:

```
awk 'f{print; next} {buf[NR]=$0} /two/{print "FOUND"; for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print buf[i]; f=1}'
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file | awk 'f{print; next} {buf[NR]=$0} /two/{print "FOUND"; for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print buf[i]; f=1}'
FOUND
one
two
two
three
```

That awk script will also work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box.

Comment: sed is a stream editor, and I'm editing a stream.

Comment: sed isn't only for editing streams and you said multiple times in your question that you were operating on a file - "I'd like to add a line on top of my output if my input **file** has a specific word" and "how to look for it in the whole **file**" and "to modify a python source **file**". If you need a solution that works for streams instead (or additionally) then fix your question to say that. I updated my answer meantime.

Comment: Sorry, my reply wasn't explicit enough. It was because you said that "sed is for doing s/old/new on individual strings". Sed stands for "Stream EDitor", its main goal is to manipulates streams of text, so reducing it to just doing substitutions is IMHO incorrect. Yes, I'm changing a file, but manipulating a file or a stream is quite the same beast with sed.

Comment: @liberforce I know what `sed` means, I've been using it for almost 40 years and I'm one of the top [answerers of sed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/topusers) on this forum. Strings can come from streams or files, there's no implication that "string" means "file". My point is that if you're using sed constructs other than just those required to do simple substitutions on strings (i.e. s, g, and p (with -n)) such as trying to match a regexp across a whole file and then insert a string at the front of that file then sed is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: sed might not be the best tool for the job, but I already have a bunch of expressions in a sed file, and I'd prefer add a a few lines to that script (even if it's a bit complicated and suboptimal), rather than use a separate method afterwards. The whole point of my question "is this doable with sed, and how?", not "is sed the best tool for this job?".

Comment: OK, good luck with that. You might want to include your existing sed script in your question as adding to an existing script will make things significantly more difficult than writing a new sed script just for this. You should also state what version of sed you're using as the answer (if one is possible as an addition to an existing script) will almost certainly not be portable across all seds.